# phonegap and videoplayer plugin with pre loader status

Tags: android, cordova

I'm finding a way to add pre loading dailog to phonegap video player plugin (more info and java code please see https://github.com/dawsonloudon/VideoPlayer/blob/master/src/android/VideoPlayer.java )

I tried with javascript way in many way for example add onclick before fuction before call video plugin it's not work. it's seem that cordova (phonegap) will excute from plugin before javascript.

I try to add dialog (suggested by [How to preload an Activity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8193394/how-to-preload-an-activity) ) but still not work (may be I didn't good in java code).

Please suggest me.

Thank you,
Umpol

Comment: what is actual issue?you are not getting dialog or else?

Comment: Yes I'm not getting dialog.

Comment: Are you using AsyncTask for any background operation you want to run before activity launch?